# Pulling YouTube viewCount

Tags: php, json, wordpress, youtube

I'm trying to pull my viewcount from youtube through a php script and I'm having some issues.

My code is below. It doesn't seem to be working at all.

```
<?php
    $video_ID = '<?php echo(types_render_field("youtube-id", array())); ?>';
    $JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?    v=2&alt=json");
    $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
    $views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
    echo $views;
?>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you checked `$video_ID` and `$JSON_Data`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the api but i believe this is how it should be:

```
<?php
    $video_ID = types_render_field("youtube-id", array());
    $JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json");
    $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
    $views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
    echo $views;
?>
```

You had passed a string as the video id, see my changes

Comment: Anther problem this causes tho-ugh, is a slow page load, is there anyway to do this after content loads?

Comment: For slow page load, i think you will have to prefecth the data and save it to your database instead of doing a file_get_contents at every request.